# Knockout computed is not re-evaluating even though observable within that computed is being changed

Tags: knockout.js

I've noticed that some things that were working fine in my app seem to be less than fine recently and it coincided with updating knockout to 2.3.0 in nuget in visual studio - that may, of course, be coincidental!

I have a simple throttled observable which I subscribe to:

```
    this.throttledValue.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        return datacontext.checkComparisonExists(comparisonCode()).then(function (res) {
            isDuplicateComparisonCode(res);
        });
    });
```

and I push the result of the ajax lookup (true/false) into my `isDuplicateComparisonCode` observable.

I also have the following var function:

```
var canSave = ko.computed(function () {
    return hasChanges() && !isSaving() && !isDuplicateComparisonCode();
});
```

which is bound to my save button:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" data-bind="click: $parent.save, enable: $parent.canSave()"><i class = icon-save></i> Save</button>
```

and the idea is that the save button is disabled whilst there are no changes (`hasChanges`), there isn't already a save going on (`!isSaving`) and the code entered is not a duplicate (`!iDuplicateComparisonCode`).

Crucial point here... this WAS working a week/two weeks ago as I have several test projects saved and I can only save when the save button is enabled, obviously!  I have not edited any code in this part of the app in over a month, all that's happened is that knockout has been updated.

In debug in chrome, the `throttledValue.subscribe` function is correctly hit every time and I can see the `isDuplicateComparisonCode` observable being successfully updated with a true or false value.

The `canSave` var function is only hit once, however, on page load and then it seems to just cache the value as 'false' therefore disabling my save button regardless of the fact that one of the observables contained within (isDuplicateComparisonCode) is being changed. I would expect the `canSave` function to be hit each and every time one of the constituent observables is updated, surely?

Edited to add: Somewhat bizarrely, the same code works perfectly on my development machine, just not live.  This is somewhat worrying as it has been republished recently and it all appears to be identical so I'm completely baffled now.

Comment: Do you use `canSave` elsewhere? Do you try to enable/disable this button outside of `canSave`?

Comment: No to both questions. The html above is the only bit that refers to `canSave`

Comment: Ok, can you show some part of your viewmodel? I'm surprised `isDuplicateComparisonCode` is called like it's global. Last thing: I guess you are sure `hasChanges` and `!isSaving` are true?

Comment: Whether they are true or not is kind of irrelevant as the `canSave` function is not even being hit on the live site. The same code on my development server is hit every single time I change the code and the `isDuplicateComparisonCode` observable is updated.  Maybe something to do with minified knockout js library compared with debug used on my dev machine or something?

Comment: Try adding this:
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
and observe hascanges and issaving. 
If either hasChanges or !isSavings is false the value of isDuplicateComparisonCode is irrelevant for canSave. (Knockout has improved the re-evalution need and may 'choose' not to rerun cansave)

Comment: Could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) sample